Closure Javascript. Why I can't get access to the inner variable if it is returned
const crateCounter = () => {
  let count = 0 

  const increment = () => {
    count++
  }
  const getCount = () => {
    return count
  }
  return { increment, getCount, count }
}

let counter = crateCounter()

counter.increment() // count is 1
counter.increment() // count is 2
counter.increment() // count is 3
console.log(counter.getCount()) // showing 3. Good!
console.log(counter.count) // showing 0. Why?

Why the method getCount() get access to the variable count but why we cannot access to the variable count itself?

It is in the definition of closure function - a closure is created when an inner function has access to the variables and parameters of its outer function, even after the outer function has finished executing. This is possible because the inner function retains a reference to the lexical environment (scope) in which it was defined

It's because you never update the the object literal that you return. Same behavior with let a = 0; const x = {a}; a++; console.log(x);. count is returned by value, not by a reference to the closure variable count.

This has nothing to do with closures (as the getCount closure is working). It's just that the variable count is independent from the object property .count (although being initialised to its value when the object is created). increment is only changing the local variable, not the property - it should do this.count++ for that. You can make it work by making the property a getter for the variable, like get count() { return count; }
